# In JavaScript, is there a way to generate a single variable to share across .js files within my project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, singleton, mocha.js, webdriver-io

I am generating an ID number (ex. 47362) via a RESTful web service.  This ID is dependent on two string parameters.  Once the ID is generated, it is assigned to a variable called `instance`.  This function is written as a singleton pattern in the file `generateID.js`:

```
//generateID.js

let Generator = require('./generator');

let GenerateID = (function () {

    let instance;

    return {
        getInstance: function (string1, string2) {
            if (!instance) {
                instance = Generator.generate(string1, string2);
            }
            return instance;
        }
    };

})();

module.exports = GenerateID;
```

What I want to do is share this variable with various test spec files, like such these two:

```
//test1.js

let expect = require('chai').expect;
let Generator = require('../../generator/generator');
let GenerateID = require('../../generator/generateID');

let TS = 'Test Suite';
let T = 'Me';

let TC = 'My First Test';

let step1 = 'step 1';
let step2 = 'step 2';

let ID = GenerateID.getInstance(TS, T);

describe(TC, function() {

    it(step1, function() {

        let result = Generator.add(2, 1);
        Generator.log(ID, step1, result);
        expect(result).to.equal(true);

    });

    it(step2, function() {

        let result = Generator.add(2, 2);
        Generator.log(ID, step2, result);
        expect(result).to.equal(true);

    });

});
```

```
//test2.js

let expect = require('chai').expect;
let Generator = require('../../generator/generator');
let GenerateID = require('../../generator/generateID');

let TS = 'Test Suite';
let T = 'Me';

let TC = 'My Second Test';

let step1 = 'step 1';
let step2 = 'step 2';

let ID = GenerateID.getInstance(TS, T);

describe(TC, function() {

    it(step1, function() {

        let result = Generator.sub(4, 2);
        Generator.log(ID, step1, result);
        expect(result).to.equal(true);

    });

    it(step2, function() {

        let result = Generatorsub(9, 4);
        Generator.log(ID, step2, result);
        expect(result).to.equal(true);

    });

});
```

When this runs on my machine, the two JS files receive two different IDs.

Is this logic not sound?  Is this not the proper way to write and share a singleton?  How can I fix my code so that both JS files receive the same ID?

Comment: What sequence of running a main file in node and requiring `test1.js` and `test2.js` reproduces the problem?

Comment: The project is run depending on the configuration of the `wdio.conf.js` file.  This project utilizes WebdriverIO.  The `wdio.conf.js` file includes a list of spec files and environments as well as other misc configurations.  More info can be found here: https://webdriver.io/docs/gettingstarted.html Does this information help?

Answer (score 0):

I've run in to this need before and the best option I found to do was generate a random ID via the command line, store that as an environment variable, then pass that in to your `wdio` command call.

Here an example using the [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env) and [date-now-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/date-now-cli) NPM packages

```
cross-env BATCH_ID=`date-now` wdio
```

Then in my test, I can get the ID via `process.env`:

```js
describe('Test Case', function() {
    it('Should log ID', function() {
        console.log('ID:', process.env.BATCH_ID)
    });
})
```

One thing to know is that each test file in WebdriverIO is spawned in [a child Node process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html), so they all require files separately. That's why sharing between doesn't work.

You could also take a look at [the `global` Node variable](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global), and attach your generator function to a `global.generator` variable inside your wdio.conf.js file.

Comment: Thank you Kevin! However, I can't generate an ID via your recommendation.  The ID is generated via a RESTful web service, so I cannot use the `date-now` approach.  What I am looking to do is generate the ID once with the given parameters `(string1, string2)` and store that variable so that both `test1.js` and `test2.js` can access the variable.  The global node variable seems like the right direction, however I would need an example on how to implement this.  I am new to WDIO and need all the help I can get!  Thank you so much for taking the time to help me!

Comment: It's not exactly the same, but I cover how to create a global variable in the wdio.conf.js file in this youtube video of mine (skip to 4 minute mark): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9xjBG1775Kk